# How should I optimize these if/elseif branches for speed?

Tags: python, optimization

Suppose I have the following python code:

```
a = b = 0

if f(a) and (g(b) == 1):
    # Do Something #1
    pass

elif f(a) and (g(b) == 2):
    # Do Something #1
    pass
```

You can assume that the functions `f()` and `g()` take up some non-negligible amount of CPU resource.

I want to optimize this code for computational efficiency. Should I change it to the following?

```
a = b = 0

if f(a):
    x = g(b)
    if x == 1:
        # Do Something #1
        pass
    elif x == 2:
        # Do Something #2
        pass
```

Is there any way to automate this optimization? I hate doing it by hand throughout my entire codebase.

**EDIT:**
The functions `f()` and `g()` are completely deterministic. IE: they always return the same results if given the same input parameters. And they have no side effects outside their own stack context.

Comment: Won't that depend entirely upon how often each of the three expressions will evaluated to True/1/2?

Comment: have you **profiled** this? if not that is **work you can do!** this is not a valid question unless you have profiled this, **pin pointed** a bottleneck and have a specific question about that bottleneck. as it is, this is a **do my work for me** question.

Comment: [learn](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) how to profile

Comment: You could do `f_a = f(a)` and `g_b = g(b)` in front of the tests to avoid doing it twice, but that would/could limit the usefullness of boolean circuit operations. But the main question is _why do you want to optimize it_?  No need to optimize it, if is not a major time consumer in your program...

Comment: first block of code will run `f()` twice and `g()` twice at most, where as second block of code will do so once each at most.

Comment: Gimme break Jarrod Roberson. It's a valid question. How am I supposed to know that I should profile it without asking? Do I have ESP? Taesu's answer was much more helpful.

Comment: C++ compiler would optimize such things for me. I'm wondering if there is any kind of automated code-optimization tool that would go through my entire python code-base and find all such cases where it can squeeze out increased efficiencies.

Comment: A C++ compiler would not do that optimization for you because there's no assurance that f() and g() are side-effect free or consistent

Comment: Slightly updated the question.

Comment: Disagree about profiling. The answer to the question is surely "yes". In this case the optimised code is no harder to read than the original, so if f and g are anything but the most trivial of deterministic functions, then write it the optimized way.

Answer (score 4):

Using a single if for the `f(a)` is definitely more efficient. For optimal efficiency you should store the result of expensive common sub-expressions in a variable:

```
if f(a):
    gb = g(b)
    if gb == 1:
        ...
    if gb == 2:
        ...
```

This will execute these functions as seldom as possible

---

If `g(b)` can also return a value that does not match any `if`, then you should profile - it could be beneficial to calculate `g(b)` first and see if it returned any valid value, and only then calculate `f(a)` (if these are not dependent of course):

```
gb = g(b)
if gb in (1, 2) and f(a):
    if gb == 1:
        ...
    if gb == 2:
```

---

There is no way that any standard Python compiler could statically optimize these unlike in C/C++ where the function contents can be inlined.